# Fatla Error Fatal error: Cannot redeclare

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, ubuntu-14.04

I am going through the tutorial located here [Introduction to Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/ref/overview.html) and everthing works until I navigate to **localhost/album** I am getting an error of

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Album\Controller\AlbumController::indexAction() in /var/www/project/testingpj/module/Album/src/Album/Controller/AlbumController.php on line 27
>   Call Stack
>       Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1   0.0001  228936  {main}( )   ../index.php:0
>   2   0.0491  2160776 Zend\Mvc\Application->run( )    ../index.php:17
>   3   0.0501  2174648 Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger( )  ../Application.php:313
>   4   0.0501  2174648 Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners( ) ../EventManager.php:207
>   5   0.0503  2176408 call_user_func ( )  ../EventManager.php:468
>   6   0.0503  2176976 Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch( )    ../EventManager.php:468
>   7   0.0504  2177280 Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager->get( )   ../DispatchListener.php:96
>   8   0.0504  2177608 Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get( )   ../ControllerManager.php:137
>   9   0.0505  2177608 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get( )  ../AbstractPluginManager.php:103
>   10  0.0505  2178976 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create( )   ../ServiceManager.php:525
>   11  0.0505  2179264 Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate( ) ../ServiceManager.php:593
>   12  0.0506  2179456 Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->createFromInvokable( )   ../ServiceManager.php:637
>   13  0.0506  2179504 class_exists ( )    ../AbstractPluginManager.php:167
>   14  0.0506  2179816 spl_autoload_call ( )   ../AbstractPluginManager.php:167
>   15  0.0506  2180328 Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader->autoload( ) ../AbstractPluginManager.php:0
>   16  0.0506  2180600 Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader->loadClass( )    ../StandardAutoloader.php:215

I googled everything and cannot seem to find the issue. Any help is appreciated greatly. I am new to ZF.

I am running this on Ubuntu 14.04 locally using php5, apache2, Zend Framework 2.3

Please let me know if you need additional info.

Here my code:
**Module.php**

```
<?php
namespace Album;

 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
 use Album\Model\Album;
 use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
 use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
 use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

 class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
 {
         public function getAutoloaderConfig()
         {
         return array(
             'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
             __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
             ),
             'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
             'namespaces' => array(
                 __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
             ),
             ),
         );
         }

         public function getConfig()
         {
         return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
         }

         public function getServiceConfig()
         {
         return array(
             'factories' => array(
             'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                 $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                 $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                 return $table;
             },
             'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                 $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                 $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                 $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                 return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
             },
             ),
         );
     }
}
?>
```

**AlbumController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Album\Controller;

 use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
 use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;


     class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
     {
             protected $albumTable;

             public function getAlbumTable()
             {
             if (!$this->albumTable) {
                 $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
                 $this->albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
             }
             return $this->albumTable;
             }
             public function indexAction()
             {
             return new ViewModel(array(
                 'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
             ));
             }

             public function indexAction()
             {
             }

             public function addAction()
             {
             }

             public function editAction()
             {
             }

             public function deleteAction()
             {
             }

 }
?>
```

Comment: two times declared `indexAction()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two index action methods:

```
         public function indexAction()
         {
         return new ViewModel(array(
             'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
         ));
         }

         public function indexAction()
         {
         }
```

Comment: OMG I can't believe I missed that... Thanks!